# How do you apply $\infty$-topos theory to topos theory?

Tags: topos-theory

I try to learn topos theory from Johnstone's book referred to as the 'elephant'.
So, by a **topos** I mean a cartesian closed category with subobject classifier.

Every Grothendieck topos is a topos. Every topos is a quasi-topos.
So, for example, a result about quasi-topos may be applied to a topos or to a Grothendieck topos.
I mention these facts as simple instances of precise relations between mathematical concepts.

What is the precise relation between $\infty$-topos and topos?
(I am looking for a rigorous answer that in particular clarifies how the theory of $\infty$-topos may be applied to topos theory.)

Thnx.

Comment: So what reference are you using for $\infty$-toposes?

Comment: The nLab and Lurie's book. But cannot get far without an answer to the question above.

Comment: An $\infty$-topos in the sense of Lurie "contains" a Grothendieck topos (namely, the full subcategory of 0-truncated objects), but other than trivial examples, no $\infty$-topos is a topos and no topos is an $\infty$-topos. (You might call this a category error, hah.)

Comment: @ZhenLin, are you implying that one cannot apply $\infty$-topos theory to topos theory? This might well be the case; I certainly don't know how to. Anyway, it would be useful if you could expand you comment to an answer.